# booting ubuntu alongside windows 10 home

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04

I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu off an 64 gb sd card on my acer computer with windows 10 and it wont work!! I'm new at this, so can someone PLEASE tell me what I'm doing wrong????

Comment: Please tell us what went wrong and any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

you can boot your ubuntu live usb/dvd/cd install ubuntu to your sd card. during boot you can press a key to select boot device and you need to select that sd-card for ubuntu or your harddrive for windows